# Not understanding the syntax for latLngBounds in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

The leaflet latLngBounds() function has a method getCenter() but I don't understand the syntax to return that value.

```
var mk5 = L.latLngBounds.getCenter(); returns an error
var mk5 = L.latLngBounds().getCenter(); returns an error
var mk5 = L.latLngBounds({getCenter()}); returns an error
```

Finding an example of its use is impossible. Someone please show me the syntax of using this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [doc](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#latlngbounds) indicates:

1. Create first  corner: `var corner1 = L.latLng(40.712, -74.227);`
2. Create second corner: `var corner2 = L.latLng(40.774, -74.125);`
3. Create bounds: `bounds = L.latLngBounds(corner1, corner2);`
4. Call `getCenter` method from `bounds` instance: `bounds.getCenter()`

Here is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>



  </head>

  <body>



    <div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <script>
      var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 2);

      L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
          '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
          'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1
      }).addTo(mymap);

      var corner1 = L.latLng(40.712, -74.227),
        corner2 = L.latLng(40.774, -74.125),
        bounds = L.latLngBounds(corner1, corner2)

      var rect = L.rectangle(bounds, {
        color: 'blue',
        weight: 1
      }).addTo(mymap);

      mymap.fitBounds(bounds)


      const markerCoords = bounds.getCenter()

      L.marker(markerCoords).addTo(mymap)

    </script>



  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why is the result in longitude/latitude order?

Comment: The return value of `bounds.getCenter()` is an instance of `L.LatLng`, [as documented](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#latlngbounds-getcenter).